# Android returning null ListView when findViewById

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I've created a custom dialog (with a List View):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/placeholder"
    android:scaleType="center" />
<!--android:src="@drawable/app_dialog_header" -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/pokemon_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="343dp"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However , when I try to invoke it from MainActivity (using       findViewById(R.id.pokemon_list_view);
) I get null :

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' 
on a null object reference
```

.

```
     final ArrayList<Pokemon> pokemons = databaseAccess.getAllPokemonWithTypes(type1, type2);

    // load the customized_dialog.xml layout and inflate to view
    LayoutInflater layoutinflater = getLayoutInflater();

    pokemonFoundListView = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.pokemon_list_view);
    pokemonAdapter = new PokemonAdapter(this, pokemons);
    pokemonFoundListView.setAdapter(pokemonAdapter);

    View customizedUserView = (View) layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.customized_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(customizedUserView);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(pokemonAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

BUT , If I place this ListView in my content_main.xml (MainActivty view) , Android finds it . I supose that the problem here is that I cant reference another element from another XML view that isn't my content_main.xml .

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to invoke findViewById on your custome view

```
    ...

    View customizedUserView = (View) layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.customized_dialog, null);

    pokemonFoundListView = (ListView) customizedUserView.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_list_view);

    ...
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog is added to the view hierarchy in a lazy way.

Therefore if you try to find the listview (inside the dialog view) from your activity root view, it will not be found. (think ViewStub).

But the view is inside your dialog, therefore

```
View customizedUserView = (View) layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.customized_dialog, null);
pokemonFoundListView = (ListView)  customizedUserView.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_list_view);
```

Will correctly find the view.